# Solidity fallback function with Ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

What is the recommended way to call the Solidity fallback() function with Ethers.js ? https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/contracts.html#fallback-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [send](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-sendTransaction) an empty transaction

```
let tx = {
    to: contractAddress
};

await signer.sendTransaction(tx);
```

Comment: How to get response data from sendTransaction?  
var x = await signer.sendTransaction(tx); --> just returns big object with no response data?

Comment: It doesn't return the "contract function return value" when you're creating a transaction. But within the fallback function, you can set a property or emit an event, and that will be accessible using Ethers.js. See my answer to your other question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67240956/1693192.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67208641/10871073) is not precise (technically). Sending an empty transaction to a contract will trigger the `receive()` function first. Only if the contract has no `receive()` function, the `fallback()` will be triggered (as per the solidity [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html?highlight=receive#receive-ether-function))

If you want to make sure to call the `fallback()` function of a contract, you should send a transaction with non-empty data:

```
let tx = {
    to: contractAddress,
    data: "0x0000dead", // can't be just "0x0"
};

await signer.sendTransaction(tx);
```