# How to get Ethers.js response data

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js

Solidity:

```
function ping() public view returns ( uint ) {
    return 999999999;
}
function ping2() public returns ( uint ) {
    return 999999999;
}
```

Javascript Ethers.js:

```
(await contract.ping()).toString();  //-> 999999999  ( correct ) 
(await contract.ping2()).toString(); //-> [object Object] ( ?? )
```

Why does ping2 return [Object Object] ?  How to get the data from ping2?

Also:

```
(await contract.sendTransaction(txObj)).toString(); //-> [object Object] ( ?? )
```

Why does using sendTransaction also return [object Object] ?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a great solution from [Force Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025256/6082973) using Events.

In a nutshell:

```
const tx = await contract.transfer(...args); // 100ms
const rc = await tx.wait(); // 0ms, as tx is already confirmed
const event = rc.events.find(event => event.event === 'Transfer');
const [from, to, value] = event.args;
console.log(from, to, value);
```

Answer (score 7):

> (await contract.ping()).toString();  //-> 999999999  ( correct )

`ping()` is a `view` function - you can just call it without creating a transaction. So ethers.js doesn't create a transaction and just returns result of the call.

---

> (await contract.ping2()).toString(); //-> [object Object] ( ?? )
>
> Why does using sendTransaction also return [object Object] ?

`ping2()` is a regular `public` function. Which suggests that you need to create a transaction to execute it (even though **in this case** it doesn't make any state changes so it could be a view function as well).

Ethers.js returns the transaction data instead of the contract function return value, when you're creating a transaction.

There are few ways to read values that the transaction produced using Ethers.js.

- In this case, `ping2()` doesn't make any state changes and doesn't even read any blockchain data, so it could be a `pure` function. If it were reading blockchain data, it would be a `view` function... In both cases, `ethers.js` returns the result of the function **call** (not tx).
- Transaction to a setter and [calling a getter](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--reading).

  ```
  contract MyContract {
      uint256 value;

      function setValue(uint256 _value) public {
          value = _value;
      }

      function getValue() public view returns (uint256) {
          return value;
      }
  }
  ```

  First you create a transaction that executes the `setValue()` function, and then you make a call to `getValue()` (without transaction, so it returns the value in your JS).
- Reading event logs that your transaction produced

  ```
  event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount);

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) public {
      emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
  }
  ```

  You can get the [transaction receipt](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionReceipt) that also contains the event logs (in this case, the `Transfer` event and its values).

Comment: Just trying to get data from calls to https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies

Comment: @OmSolari Using a proxy contract doesn't make any difference. You just need to distinguish between a call (no state changes) and a transaction (can make state changes), and the answer explains that it's not possible to get a return value from a **transaction** (it's possible to get it from a call), and also shows few workarounds.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it possible to make a call to the fallback function of proxy contract? And if so whats the syntax using ethers.js? ( since fallback function doesn't exist in abi )

Comment: I don't know the answer right away. But that's a separate question, so you should ask a new question here on StackOverflow, so that someone else will be able to answer that.

Comment: ok i posted it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259069/how-to-get-response-data-from-fallback-function-of-proxy-contract-using-ethers-j